# Bitnami Helm Chart not working due to startup probe fail

Tags: mysql, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Bitnami MySQL Helm Chart (Version 8.8.6) with image tag of 5.7. MySQL container is killed without any meaningful logs. From the K8s logs, the message is as below.

```
Startup probe failed: mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.                   mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

The values.yaml I'm using is as below.

```
mysql:
  image:
    tag: 5.7
  auth:
    database: ${DATABASE}
    username: ${USERNAME}
    password: ${PASSWORD}
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: rds-backup
    annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::${ID}:role/mysql-dump-v1"
  primary:
    service:
      type: NodePort
      nodePort: 30006
    initContainers:
    - name: sql-loader
      image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - echo "Loading the backup snapshot from S3 ..." &&
        aws s3 cp s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/backup.sql /workdir/backup.sql
      volumeMounts:
      - name: loaded-sql
        mountPath: "/workdir"
    extraVolumes:
    - name: loaded-sql
      emptyDir: {}
    extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: loaded-sql
      mountPath: "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    containerSecurityContext:
      enabled: true
      runAsUser: 0
```

I generated the backup.sql from the Aurora MySQL cluster. The .sql file is saved in S3 Bucket. Database, Username, Password specified in the values.yaml are same to the ones set at the original Aurora MySQL cluster. The original Aurora MySQL cluster version is 5.7, which is the same version I'm trying to spin up using the Helm Chart.

Comment: This question is about configuring and running a container, not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Serverfault sister site of SO deals with questions about infrastructure - even if it is virtual.